# Problema al guardar objetos en un array?

Tags: java

soy nuevo por acá, y ando metido en el mundo de java y en particular con un error, esta es mi clase Persona, y esta es mi primera pregunta en este foro. Soy nuevo en Java.

```
package persona;

public class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellidoPat;
    private int edad;

    public Persona(String nombre, String apellidoPat, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidoPat = apellidoPat;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidoPat() {
        return apellidoPat;
    }

    public void setApellidoPat(String apellidoPat) {
        this.apellidoPat = apellidoPat;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
}

Y esta es mi clase principal

package persona;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Principal extends JFrame {

    Persona p[] = new Persona[2];

    public JPanel panel1;
    public JPanel panel2;
    public JPanel panel3;

    public JLabel label1;
    public JLabel label2;
    public JLabel label3;

    public JTextField txtNombre;
    public JTextField txtApellidoPat;
    public JTextField txtEdad;

    public JButton btnGuardar;
    public JButton btnRegistrados;
    public JButton btnLimpiar;
    public JButton btnSalir;

    //Aquí dentro del constructor, inicializo y creo las instancias 
     correspondientes de los objetos declarados
    public Principal() {
        super();
        this.setSize(550, 320);
        this.setTitle("Registro de usuarios");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 4));
        panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        panel3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 6));

        label1 = new JLabel("Nombre:");
        label1.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
        label2 = new JLabel("Apellido Paterno:");
        label2.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
        label3 = new JLabel("Edad:");
        label3.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 25));

        txtNombre = new JTextField("");
        txtNombre.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        txtApellidoPat = new JTextField("");
        txtApellidoPat.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        txtEdad = new JTextField("");
        txtEdad.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        btnGuardar = new JButton("Guardar");
        btnGuardar.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        btnRegistrados = new JButton("Ver registrados");
        btnRegistrados.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        btnLimpiar = new JButton("Limpiar campos");
        btnLimpiar.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        btnSalir = new JButton("Salir");
        btnSalir.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        btnGuardar.setToolTipText("Guarda la información del usuario actual");
        btnRegistrados.setToolTipText("Ver usuarios registrados");
        btnLimpiar.setToolTipText("Limpia todos los campos");
        btnSalir.setToolTipText("Salir de la aplicación");

        Container contenedor = getContentPane();
        contenedor.add(panel1);
        panel1.add(panel2);
        panel1.add(panel3);

        panel2.add(label1);
        panel2.add(txtNombre);
        panel2.add(label2);
        panel2.add(txtApellidoPat);
        panel2.add(label3);
        panel2.add(txtEdad);

        panel3.add(btnGuardar);
        panel3.add(btnRegistrados);
        panel3.add(btnLimpiar);
        panel3.add(btnSalir);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        btnGuardar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    String nom, apep;
                    int edad;
                for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                    nom = txtNombre.getText();
                    //p[i].setNombre(nom);
                    apep = txtApellidoPat.getText();
                    //p[i].setApellidoPat(apep);
                    edad = Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText());
                    //p[i].setEdad(edad);
                    p[i] = new Persona(nom,apep,edad);
                }
            }
        });

        btnRegistrados.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                String cad = "NOMBRE            APELLIDO PATERNO            EDAD            \n";
                for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                    cad = cad + p[i].getNombre() + "                            "
                            + p[i].getApellidoPat() + "                             "
                            + p[i].getEdad() + "                "
                            + "\n";
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cad);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Principal p1 = new Principal();
        p1.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

A la hora de ejecutar y guardar el primer usuario que añada, se guarda, pero cuando añado un segundo usuario, este, remplaza al primero que añadí y cuando quiero ver los usuarios que agregué, me aparece el último dos veces(repetido);
Qué estoy haciendo mal? gracias

Comment: Que tiene que ver el error que marcas con tu codigo? mas alla de eso, si, siempre estas agregando sobre el primer item del array, nunca estas agregando items al array.

Comment: Disculpe si le molestó, me confudí, gracias por responder, checaré lo que mencionó, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día, considero que el problema está a la hora de guardar sobre un vector estático. Me explico un poco, tu tienes lo siguiente

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                String nom, apep;
                int edad;
            for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                nom = txtNombre.getText();
                //p[i].setNombre(nom);
                apep = txtApellidoPat.getText();
                //p[i].setApellidoPat(apep);
                edad = Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText());
                //p[i].setEdad(edad);
                p[i] = new Persona(nom,apep,edad);
            }
        }
```

Lo que puedo entender es que cada vez que guardas entras al ciclo for y el operador "i" vuelve a quedar en cero, por esta razón siempre te va a guardar en la posición cero del vector.

**Solución rápida**

Personalmente utilizo los ArrayList (son vectores pero más sencillos para el progamador). Podrías reemplazar la siguiente linea --> `Persona p[] = new Persona[2];` ... por `List<Persona> p = new ArrayList();` y cuando quieras guardar formas el objeto persona y lo agregas al array de la siguiente manera -->

```
p.add(new persona(nombre,apellido,edad));
```

De esta manera puedes crear las personas que desees y se guardarán en una posición diferente. Cuando quieras recorrer el array lo haces con un ciclo for

```
for(int i=0; i< p.size();i++)
{
  p.get(i).getNombre();
  p.get(i).getApellido();
  p.get(i).getEdad();
}
```

Espero haber podido ayudarte.